facet figure - polynomial + linear in Altair
I want to make a facet figure with Linear and Polynomial regression in Altair. Stacking together scatter and regression plots seems understandable. However, adding additional polynomial analysis seems problematic. I cannot display the result. I was trying to go around by making a degree list for 1, 3, and 5 as in Altair Gallery, and I was unsuccessful again.
Can you help me understand the issue?
Here is my data snippet:
years = list(range(2024, 2051))
rcp_scenarios = ['RCP2.6', 'RCP4.5', 'RCP6.0', 'RCP8.5']
data = {"YEAR": years} 
for rcp in rcp_scenarios:
   data[rcp] = np.random.uniform(low=500, high=2000, size=len(years))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["YEAR"], value_vars=rcp_scenarios, 
                        var_name="RCP", value_name="RR")


And here is my Altair snippet:
scatter = alt.Chart(All_RCP_Df_yearly).mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
    x=alt.X('YEAR'),
    y=alt.Y('RR', title="Annual Precipitation [mm]"),
    color='RCP',
    tooltip=['YEAR', 'RR', 'RCP'])

linear_regression = alt.Chart(All_RCP_Df_yearly).transform_regression(
    'YEAR', 'RR', method='linear', groupby=['RCP']
).mark_line(opacity=0.75).encode(
    x='YEAR',
    y='RR',
    color='RCP')

polynomial_regression = alt.Chart(All_RCP_Df_yearly).transform_regression(
    'YEAR', 'RR', method='poly', order=2, groupby=['RCP']
).mark_line(opacity=0.75, strokeDash=[5, 3]).encode(
    x='YEAR',
    y='RR',
    color='RCP')

chart = scatter + linear_regression + polynomial_regression

chart = chart.facet(
    columns=2,
    facet=alt.Facet('RCP'))

chart.display()


When I run your code (after changing the plotted df to df_melted instead of the undefined variable and adding .scale(zero=False) to the x-axis), I get the chart below. It looks to me like both regression lines are working, could you elaborate on the issue you are experiencing?


Thanks! It seems an issue was in dtype (datetime is more stable) and I updated the Altair on the server... scale(zero=False) also helped..
